# How can I get the id of an object through an interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have the following interfaces. In the Cart interface, on the line product I want to collect only the id connected to the product interface.

At the moment I am collecting the entire object Product. What is the best way to retrieve ONLY the id of that object? What's the best syntax?

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    year: number;
    added: string;
    productCategory: ProductCategory[];
}

export interface Cart {
    product: Product;
    quantity: number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Pick`:

```
export interface Cart {
    product: Pick<Product, 'id'>;
    quantity: number;
}
```

See docs for more details: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk